# Nested if statement?

Tags: android, if-statement

I'm trying to make a button that puts text that I need in TextView on specific EditText conditions, when EditText is empty, TextView is showing right text, but when I write numbers into the EditText field and press the button - program crashes.

```
    public void Guess(View view) {
    EditText Spejimas = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.guess);
    Tekstas = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    if (Spejimas.getText().length() == 0) {
        Tekstas.setText("Oops, you forgot to type your guess!");
    } else if (Spejimas.getText().length() != 0) {
        int Guessas = Integer.parseInt(Spejimas.toString());
        if (Guessas == number) {
            Tekstas.setText("Congratulations! You got it right!");
        } else if (Guessas > number) {
            Tekstas.setText("Your number is too high, try again!");
        } else if (Guessas < number) {
            Tekstas.setText("Your number is too low, try again!");
        }
    }
}
```

I want TextView to say: "Congratulations! You got it right!", when Guessas is equal to number, "Your number is too high, try again!", when Guessas is higher than number and "Your number is too low, try again!", when Guessas is lower than number.

When I'm pressing the button that triggers this block of code when EditText has number(s) in it, program crashes.

Comment: `int Guessas = Integer.parseInt(Spejimas.getText());` maybe.

Comment: And why does it crash?  Post the logcat, it will tell you where the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code from

```
int Guessas = Integer.parseInt(Spejimas.toString());
```

to

```
int Guessas = Integer.parseInt(Spejimas.getText().toString());
```

Problem is `Integer.parseInt()` excepting string value containing only numbers. Here you are  trying to send the `edittext` as string. While converting edit text to string which contains characters other than numbers.

Comment: Because he is trying to parse the edittext object instead of the text containing by the edittext.

Comment: Ok. Please make a habit of explaining your answer right away, always

Comment: Ok.. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll keep this in mind going forward. :)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you don't cast the value that getText method returns. The getText returns Editable. You should add toString() method to everywhere you call getText, like this:

```
if (Spejimas.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
    Tekstas.setText("Oops, you forgot to type your guess!");
} else if (Spejimas.getText().toString().length() != 0) {
    int Guessas = Integer.parseInt(Spejimas.getText().toString());
    if (Guessas == number) {
        Tekstas.setText("Congratulations! You got it right!");
    } else if (Guessas > number) {
        Tekstas.setText("Your number is too high, try again!");
    } else if (Guessas < number) {
        Tekstas.setText("Your number is too low, try again!");
    }
}
```

And also, you have an issue in this line:

```
int Guessas = Integer.parseInt(Spejimas.toString());
```

You should change it to this:

```
int Guessas = Integer.parseInt(Spejimas.getText().toString());
```